# Publish website built with .net core 2.2 on Shared hosting

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, hosting

I am trying to publish a website which built using Asp.net Core 2.2 on shared hosting (A2 Hosting) after deploying the website using VS 2017 web deploy it produces 500 internal server error.

after Contacting support they told me that:
run the Windows Hosting packages for .NET Core, we do not install the SDK on these servers. 
we provide .NET core runtime installed on the host.
NET Core SDKs installed:
No SDKs were found.

.NET Core runtimes installed:
Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.2.1 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]

I am running asp.net core 2.2 app:
[image]

[image]

How can I deploy a website using proper SDK on Shared hosting?

Comment: This sounds like something you need to continue with the host because its not something that we can help with on a managed service.

Comment: Take a look at "self-contained" .NET Core applications.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/#self-contained-deployments-scd < this

Comment: Please check this tutorial https://windowswebhostingreview.com/asp-net-core-hosting-3-simple-steps-to-fix-502-5-error-in-asp-net-core/ how to deploy .net core.